# Define New Template Group in CI Template Library

Tags: codeigniter, templates

I've been trying to define a new template group in the codeigniter template library but I keep getting an error saying that group does not exist/has not been defined.  Below is the code that defines the default template group which is set to active.

```
$template['default']['template'] = 'templates/welcome';
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
   'header' => array('content' => array("<h1>Adrian's Branch</h1>")),
   'content',
   'footer' => array('content' => array('<p id="copyright">0bytes</p>'))
);
$template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['default']['parse_template'] = FALSE;
```

I figure the same methods apply in defining a custom group by replacing 'default' with the name of my custom group name?

In my controller I call...

```
$this->template->set_template('custom_template_name');
```

But this is not working?  Am I doing this right?

The user guide can be found here: http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out.  It was what I originally had but wasn't working and now it is.

```
//mobile template group
$template['mobile']['template'] = 'templates/mobile/welcome';
$template['mobile']['regions'] = array(
   'header' => array('content' => array("<h1>Adrian's Branch</h1>")),
   'content',
   'footer' => array('content' => array('<p id="copyright">0bytes Mobile</p>'))
);
$template['mobile']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['mobile']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['mobile']['parse_template'] = FALSE;
```

The above code is exactly like the the default except the group name is different.  To activate this template I just call.

```
$this->template->set_template('mobile');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the naming convention of your folder and your routes file :)

Comment: I don't know how that has applies in this situation?